# VHDL: How to convert an iterator of generate block to std_logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl

I want to get binary std_logic_vector from integer inside the generate.

For example,

0 -> 0000

1 -> 0001

2 -> 0010

...

15 -> 1111

I could write 16 if-else statements for each integer number, but I don't like this idea. (What if I will have much more than 16 integer numbers?)

I've tried to use two methods, but neither of them works:
address and hit are both std_logic_vector

```
G_1 : for i in 0 to 15 generate
    address <= conv_std_logic_vector(i, 4) when hit(i) = '1';
end generate G_1;   

G_2 : for i in 0 to 15 generate
    address <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, 4)) when hit(i) = '1';
end generate G_2;
```

Also I noticed that if I use number instead of the i, it works. (Example: I get "0101" when I use conv_std_logic_vector(5, 4))

What am I doing wrong? Is there any possible way to do it using vhdl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, do not `use ieee.std_logic_arith.all`. Instead, `use ieee.numeric_std.all`, and get rid of any nasty `conv_integer` functions; the preferred style is to use types like `unsigned`, and then convert or cast these as you have in your second code example.

Moving on to your loop, you are using `generate` loop:

```
G_1 : for i in 0 to 15 generate
  address <= conv_std_logic_vector(i, 4) when hit(i) = '1';
end generate G_1;
```

This will generate 16 lines of the form:

```
address <= conv_std_logic_vector(0, 4) when hit(0) = '1';
address <= conv_std_logic_vector(1, 4) when hit(1) = '1';
address <= conv_std_logic_vector(2, 4) when hit(2) = '1';
```

etc. Since each concurrent assignment infers its own process, your design will have multiple drivers on the `address` signal, which is not allowed in a synthesis-eligible design.

It seems like the objective is to set `address` according to the lowest set (`'1'`) bit in the `hit` vector. This is called a priority encoder. Something like this would be better:

```
process (hit)
begin
  for i in 0 to 15 loop
    address <= (others => '0');  -- Default assignment, any later assignment takes priority
    if (hit(i) = '1') then
      address <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, address`length));
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;
end process;
```

Since `address` seems to represent an unsigned number, you could use type `unsigned` for this signal, and save a type cast.

Comment: And if you are using VHDL 2008 or later you can even use `u_unsigned` (unresolved) instead of `unsigned` (resolved). This way, you will get an error in multiple drive situations.